# Stuck on complying with domain verification requirements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-services, google-developers-console

Recently I have been trying to re-boot my app. This includes adding google play services to my app.
I setup a google cloud platform account and then linked it with the developer console for my app.

Next I setup the OAuth consent screen. After completing everything it asked me to verify my website and domain; I completed this step with the google search API.

Despite all of these efforts I still got the error, `Pending developer action`.
[image: Error Shown]

Here is my verified domain (blurred out for obvious reasons):

[image: Verified Domain]

After observing the documentation a little bit more, it tells me that I must continue/reply to the email thread with their `Trust and Safety team`, **but I have not received any emails from them with my developer email -**

[image: Proof]

Thanks in advance
*-James*

Comment: Any luck? I've been sitting for over a week as well with no email to respond to.

Comment: Nope, still waiting for an email. Maybe they are held up because of covid? I am not sure, but google needs to sort out their systems. The only way I can get an email is if I pay £14.99 a month to get support - which is insane!

Comment: Me too, i am stuck with this problem too, did you solved it?

Comment: @TrầnTrungHiếu The way I fixed it is you have to make sure your google cloud and google play app are linked properly, you might have two. Make sure you have a domain that is verified and sometimes you just have to wait a day or two.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will follow your instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found the solution to this problem, and I think I can safely say that this is due to human error every single time.

When linking your google play app in the developer console to google cloud it might automatically create one for you, but if you reload the page it will make a second one. You have to make sure you select the right google cloud app to link because it might not properly connect if you use the wrong one.

Once you have done this you need to create a website or link a website that has been verified (you can verify it yourself) with google. You should then be able to setup your app easily! Not every step will be instant you might sometimes have to wait a day or two for it to work.